# How to loop through years with months and points?

Tags: linux

I want to loop throgh years and months and insert them in the wget command:

```
for f in [from 1983.07 to 2017.06]; do wget https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/thredds/fileServer/cdr/isccp_hgm_agg/files/isccp-basic/hgm/ISCCP-Basic.HGM.v01r00.GLOBAL.$f.99.9999.GPC.10KM.CS00.EA1.00.nc;done
```

Comment: And what's your question about this? Also, please explain how this is related to programming

Comment: the point should be in the {198307..201706} otherwise the url would not work.

Comment: my programming problem is the point between the month and the year.

Comment: Are you trying to iterate over `1983.07 1983.08 ... 1983.12 1984.1 ...`?

Comment: yes...............         ....

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using `bash`, you can use `..` to generate a sequence of numbers.

It won't leave leading zeroes in numbers, so you need to handle the 1-digit and 2-digit months separately.

For the ranges that include full years, you can combine a year

```
for f in 1983.0{7..9} {1984..2016}.0{1..9} {1983..2016}.{10..12} 2017.0{1..6}; do
    wget "https://www.ncei.noaa.gov/thredds/fileServer/cdr/isccp_hgm_agg/files/isccp-basic/hgm/ISCCP-Basic.HGM.v01r00.GLOBAL.$f.99.9999.GPC.10KM.CS00.EA1.00.nc"
done
```

Comment: Oops, forgot about that!

Comment: Thanks but still the files with months  10, 11, 12  did not work!

Comment: I think it should get them all, but it will do them out of order. So it does all the 01..09, then all the 10..12.

Comment: Strange because it finished running but the these files were missing in the directory.

Comment: Try adding `set -x` at the beginning of the script to see all the commands as they're executing.

Comment: I checked the output of `echo 1983.0{7..9} {1984..2016}.0{1..9} {1983..2016}.{10..12} 2017.0{1..6}` and they're all included.

Comment: Bash does support leading zeros, e.g., `{07..12}`, `{01..12}`, and `{01..06}`.

Comment: @Lithis Must be version-specific, it's not working for me on my Mac. I get 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12